# Group by not working with two columns, but does with one

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have two versions of this code:

(this one works as expected, summing and grouping on meterid)

```
Dim meterReadingsAggregated As List(Of ImportMeterReadingWithCustomField) = validreads.GroupBy(Function(m) m.MeterInfo.MeterId).[Select](Function(mr) New ImportMeterReadingWithCustomField With {
                .Timestamp = mr.Last().Timestamp,
                .ChargeType = mr.Last().ChargeType,
                .Value = mr.Sum(Function(c) c.Value),
                .Register = mr.Last().Register,
                .RowNumber = mr.Last().RowNumber,
                .MeterInfo = mr.Last().MeterInfo
            }).ToList()
```

(but this one does not, I need to add grouping on timestamp on top of meterid)

```
 Dim meterReadingsAggregated As List(Of ImportMeterReadingWithCustomField) = validreads.GroupBy(Function(m) New With {m.MeterInfo.MeterId, m.Timestamp}).[Select](Function(mr) New ImportMeterReadingWithCustomField With {
                .Timestamp = mr.Last().Timestamp,
                .ChargeType = mr.Last().ChargeType,
                .Value = mr.Sum(Function(c) c.Value),
                .Register = mr.Last().Register,
                .RowNumber = mr.Last().RowNumber,
                .MeterInfo = mr.Last().MeterInfo
            }).ToList()
```

I checked timestamp values and 100% they are identical, so that's not it. I tried that second version with meterid column only and it would not work so something is not right with me using New With there but I struggle to figure it out.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: *"it would not work"* is not an acceptable description of the actual behaviour. What actually happened? What are the data types involved, so that we can test for ourselves if required?

Comment: How is timestamp determined to be the same? Maybe the string representation looks the same, but is actually of by fractions of seconds? Can you try `.Timestamp.ToString()`?

Comment: @jmcilhinney  - what I meant by not working was that it was not grouping which I thought was clear enough from the title. However I got it working just needed to add 'Key' into group: GroupBy(Function(m) New With {Key m.MeterInfo.MeterId, Key m.Timestamp}). Carlo - it is imported from CSV file where I can see them be identical. Thanks both for looking into this.

Comment: A full description of the problem includes what it IS doing, not just what it ISN'T doing. A good question also requires can reproduce the issue, which is not the case here. The assumption is often that we will just be able to read the code and know what's wrong, which is true sometimes but certainly not all the time. A full description of the problem will often help us focus on where the issue might be and the ability to reproduce the issue means that we can see the cause and the effect for ourselves.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I agree with what you are saying. But in this case just adding that extra column would stop group by from grouping so it was my assumption that it's going to be something small and silly as it was.. And I think we can agree that if someone who uses VB for Linq regularly would spot this in a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was missing 'Key' in the group.

(so this works)

```
Dim meterReadingsAggregated As List(Of ImportMeterReadingWithCustomField) = validreads.GroupBy(Function(m) New With {Key m.MeterInfo.MeterId, Key m.Timestamp}).[Select](Function(mr) New ImportMeterReadingWithCustomField With {
                .Timestamp = mr.Last().Timestamp,
                .ChargeType = mr.Last().ChargeType,
                .Value = mr.Sum(Function(c) c.Value),
                .Register = mr.Last().Register,
                .RowNumber = mr.Last().RowNumber,
                .MeterInfo = mr.Last().MeterInfo
            }).ToList()
```

It was compiling with no problems so it was not immediately obvious it's missing anything.